# Unable to find main.db file in my Local system

Tags: command-line, skype

I am unable to find the main.db file where the Skype Conversations gets stored. I use Ubuntu 18.04 OS and the latest version of Skype. Can someone please help me out to find the main.db file in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: You haven't said how you've installed `skype`.. it is *deb* package? *snap*? flatpak? etc..

Comment: Have you tried "find / | grep main.db" ?